# Perform an aggregation on a DataTable with Linq in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by, aggregate

Given a datatable, I wish to output an IEnumerable type (dictionary(of T) would be perfect, otherwise a datatable would be acceptable) that provides an aggregation of the data within the datatable.

In SQL I would write the query as such:

```
select groupByColumn, sum(someNumber) from myTable group by groupByColumn
```

In VB.NET the closest I have got to this (achieved using information [here](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/.NET/Grouping-and-Aggregating-When-Querying-LINQ-to-SQL/3/)) is:

```
' dt is a datatable containing two columns, referred to by index in p below
Dim q = From p In dt Group p By p(0) Into Sum(p(1)) Select p(0), SumOfNumber = Sum
```

However I receive error: *"Range variable name can be inferred only from a simple or qualified name with no arguments."* on the p(0) element.

Therefore my question is as follows:

1. How can I resolve this error?
2. How do I process the result (q) as an IEnumerable type?

Life isn't made any easier because I'm using Linq in unfamiliar vb.net. Many examples are in C#, but I haven't really come across anything suitable even in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved: I had to alias the columns returned.

```
Dim q = From p In dt
    Group p By transactionTypeName = p(0) _
    Into totalForType = Sum(Convert.ToDouble(p(1))) _
    Select transactionTypeName, totalForType
```

Also note that I had to do a conversion on the value that I was summing because being a dynamically returned datatable didn't have the column type specified.

Hint found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/89437f51-6254-4d50-ac1d-75bc46f32034/) because vb.net oh so helpfully gives us a different error message to C#'s *"Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access."*

For completeness, results are processed as below:

```
For Each item In q ' no need for defining item as a type (in C# we'd use the var keyword)
    If item.totalForType = magicNumber Then
        'do something
    Else
        'do something else
    End If
Next
```